# Authentication error in freeradius server

Tags: mysql, freeradius

I have installed freeradius server on Ubuntu-14.04, when I try take radtest on server using, radtest -x bob root123 127.0.0.1 1812 testing123
I get following error when I run freeradius -X,

> [sql] User bob not found
>   ++[sql] returns notfound  >++[expiration] returns noop  >++[logintime] returns noop  >[pap] WARNING! No "known good" password found for the user. >Authentication may fail because of this.  >++[pap] returns noop  >ERROR: No authenticate method (Auth-Type) found for the request: >Rejecting the user  >Failed to authenticate the user  >Using Post-Auth-Type Reject

I have added user in users file, bob Cleartext-Password := "root123"
In eap.conf file, default_eap_type = peap

Still getting an error, can anyone help me to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the text-file as a valid source for your users?
The error message seems like you just enabled sql but not the

```
    #
    #  Read the 'users' file
    files
```

in the sites-enabled/default (and innter-tunnel)
Hopefully this fixes your problem